# Correct method for adding master/child entity in breeze?

Tags: breeze

Each time I think I have it nailed, it rears its head again!

So simply if there's a master table with navigation property to a collection of children and I use "createEntity" to create a new empty version of the entity I am able to see the navigation property in the entity returned, but I am unable to access/set any properties. I suspect this is because the parent key does not yet exist in the child entity?

To clarify. I can put in a breakpoint at the point where the new entity is returned and if I inspect the master() entity I can see the children property right there.  If I then try and do:

```
master().children.childProperty("this is a new value")
```

...then I simply get "object function observable()..." (then loads of code from knockout I think) and ending "has no method 'childProperty'"

I think I've tried every combination of parentheses known to man and I get slightly different errors but nothing works.  Do I need to have a [0] in there somewhere as "children" is effectively an array?

*Added info for clarification.*

As detailed in comments below, retrieving an existing entity with "expand" specified in the query for eager loading returns a master entity with a related child entity, properties of which I can set with the method I was trying to for the "new" example above which doesn't work.  The specified length of the "children" collection when I return an existing master/child is 1, when I initialize a new master/child the array length is zero.

This isn't, I suppose, a traditional master/child relationship - it's more an associated entity than a child.  To explain, "master" will always have one child record - think of it as master being a bottle and child being the related record that determines the colour of the bottle, the contents and the label details on the bottle. There will only ever be one bottle but there could be dozens of variations of colour, content and label.

When I retrieve an existing master record, I also specify the specific child I want so in this page I will only ever retrieve one master and one child record as I'm editing the specific variation and may want to change the label text.

In another page, I list all the variations for a bottle, so there I retrieve a master and all the associated children in a classic "one to many" example.

The model is:

```
Public Class bMaster
    Public Property ID() As Integer

    ...other properties

    Public Overridable Property bChildren() As ICollection(Of bChild)
End Class

Public Class bChild
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property bMasterID() As Integer

    ...other properties

    Public Overridable Property bMaster() As bMaster
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carl - Kick yourself.  You are so close that it hurts to write this for you.  If children is a collection you can't simply set a value for each one of them like that.  Since they are an array you must select one of them to set a value on.

```
var child = master().children()[0]; // get the first child
child.childProperty(someValue);
```

This would also work this way -

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(master().children(), function (child) {
    child.childProperty(someValue);
});
```

Which would loop through your array and set the value for each of the entities in the collection.

**Edit**

If it is a new entity then it doesn't yet have a child entity.  If there is always only going to be one child entity of the parent, I am not sure why you are using a collection instead of a complex type or something.  You need to create a parent and then create a child on that parent as well -

```
var parentEntity = manager.createEntity('Parent');
var childEntity = manager.createEntity('Child');
childEntity.parent(parentEntity);
return childEntity;
```

Then if you wanted to set a property on a parent's child you would do so as I mentioned above -

```
var child = master().children()[0]; // get the first child
child.childProperty(someValue);
```

or you could still use

```
master().children()[0].childProperty(someValue);
```

Last, if you created the relationship properly (one to one instead of one to many) you could use this -

```
master().children().childProperty(someValue);
```

Comment: Hmm. Sadly not. I think I tried this at one point.  I have `var achild= master().children()[0];` and `achild=undefined` straight after.  If I add a watch to the object `master().children` it shows as an object with `latestValue: Array[0]`.  I'm creating this new entity like this: `masterObservable(manager.createEntity("master"));`  I don't need to add an "expand" on that or something to get the child entity, do I?

Comment: Further testing reveals that if I fetch an existing `master` entity and specify `expand(children)` on the query for eager loading, I get back (correctly) a master entity with the related child.  I am able to directly set a value like: `master().children()[0].childProperty('New value in here')` as well.  It seems my problem with the new entity is that there's no key in existence yet (master id is an identity field) in order to tie together the master and child.  Have added some clarification to original post.

Comment: The answer that I posted addresses your original question.  The reason you aren't able to find any children on a brand new entity is that there aren't any yet.  If it is a brand new entity it does have an id on master, should be a negative number, but it won't have any children until you create or add then

Comment: That doesn't seem to be entirely the case though - or more likely I'm misinterpreting what I'm seeing!  The new master entity clearly has a property for the related child entity (via foreign key/navigation property) which I can see with the property inspector in google dev tools. It is, of course, showing as an object array of zero length.  This is what confuses me... should I be explicitly creating the related entity?  If so, how is that done as there's only "createEntity" in breeze and the documentation doesn't show anything to do with related entity creation.

Comment: I updated my answer to include how to create two related properties.  The zero length array is an empty collection.

Comment: So even though createEntity() on the master record has, well, a "ghost" property of a related entity that doesn't exist yet, I need to explicitly create the child entity and then use the `.parent()` method to explicitly connect the two together and enable the child properties to be accessed via the parent?  Or alternatively I could keep accessing the child properties directly via the new child object and then simply combine the two on saving the changes?

Comment: By the way, it's not always only one child to a master - I gave the example: "There will only ever be one bottle but there could be dozens of variations of colour, content and label." - and each colour/variation is a child.

Comment: No, your are looking at it wrong.  I assume child has a parentid and a navigation property of parent.  That is why child has a parent() function it can call

Comment: Ah. I see.  No, as per the model shown in my edited post, the navigation property is "bMaster" on the child.  So in this instance after creating both entities manually, I can then call childEntity.bMaster(masterEntity) and that "cements" the link?  Or, as I suggested, I can leave them separate and work on them separately until I save the changes at which point I can join them together as described?

Comment: Yes, you can do it either way.  If you associate the two and the child doesn't have all of it's required properties set yet, and it is data-bound to a list or something in the DOM, you may break a binding.  A simple fix for this is to use the $data. prepend.  You can also set childEntity.bMaster(null) if you wanted to clear the relationship, just probably won't be able to save until it is set.